# inserting data to 2 joined tables using jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

i am new to sring boot and jpa so i am trying to make an api that takes cutomer class and phone number class

Customer:

```
package com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "c_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "c_address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Phonenumber.class,mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Phonenumber phone;

    public Customer() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", phone=" + phone +
                '}';
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Phonenumber getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Phonenumber phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Customer( String name, String address, Phonenumber phone) {

        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Phone number:

```
package com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "phonenumber")
public class Phonenumber {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "p_number", nullable = false)
    private String number;
    @Column(name = "c_code", nullable = false)
    private String ccode;
    @Column(name = "c_name", nullable = false)
    private String cname;
    @Column(name = "o_name", nullable = false)
    private String oname;

    public Phonenumber() { }

    public Phonenumber(String number, String ccode, String cname, String oname) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.ccode = ccode;
        this.cname = cname;
        this.oname = oname;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getCcode() {
        return ccode;
    }
    public void setCcode(String ccode) {
        this.ccode = ccode;
    }

    public String getCname() {
        return cname;
    }
    public void setCname(String cname) {
        this.cname = cname;
    }

    public String getOname() {
        return oname;
    }
    public void setOname(String oname) {
        this.oname = oname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Phonenumber [id=" + id + ", number=" + number + ", ccode=" + ccode + ", cname=" + cname + ", oname="
                + oname + "]";
    }
}
```

CustomerController:

```
package com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity.Customer;
import com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.repository.CustomerRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@CrossOrigin
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerrepository;

    @GetMapping("/customer1")
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        return customerrepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/customer6/{id}")
    public Optional<Customer> getcustomerById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long customerid) {
        return customerrepository.findById(customerid);
    }

    @PostMapping("/customer")
    public Customer create (@RequestBody Customer newcustomer) {
        return customerrepository.save(newcustomer);
    }

//    @PutMapping("/customer3/{id}")
//    public ResponseEntity<Customer> update(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long customerid,
//                                           @RequestBody Customer numberDetails){
//        Customer x = customerrepository.getById(customerid);
//
//        x.setName(numberDetails.getName());
//        x.setAddress(numberDetails.getAddress());
//        x.setPhoneid(numberDetails.getPhoneid());
//
//        final Customer updatedcustomer = customerrepository.save(x);
//        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedcustomer);
//    }
    @DeleteMapping("/customer2/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long customerid) {
        Customer u = customerrepository.getById(customerid);
        customerrepository.delete(u);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }

}
```

PhonenumberController:

```
package com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber.PhoneNumber;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity.Phonenumber;
import com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.repository.PhoneNumberRepository;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class PhonenumberController {
    @Autowired
    private PhoneNumberRepository phonenumberrepository;

    @GetMapping("/phonenumber")
    public List<Phonenumber> getAllPhonenumbers() {
        return phonenumberrepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/phonenumber/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Phonenumber> getnumberById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long numberid) {
        Phonenumber t = phonenumberrepository.getById(numberid);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(t);
    }
    @PostMapping("/phonenumber6")
    public Phonenumber create(@RequestBody Phonenumber pnumber) {
        return phonenumberrepository.save(pnumber);
    }

    @PutMapping("/phonenumber1/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Phonenumber> update(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long numberid,
                                              @RequestBody Phonenumber numberDetails){
        Phonenumber x = phonenumberrepository.getById(numberid);

        x.setNumber(numberDetails.getNumber());
        x.setCcode(numberDetails.getCcode());
        x.setCname(numberDetails.getCname());
        x.setOname(numberDetails.getOname());

        final Phonenumber updatednumber = phonenumberrepository.save(x);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatednumber);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/phonenumber2/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long numberid) {
        Phonenumber u = phonenumberrepository.getById(numberid);
        phonenumberrepository.delete(u);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
}
```

So I need help to know how I can insert the customer and the phone number in the database with a join relation between the custmer and the phonenumber and I have this error also:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity.Customer.phone, referenced property unknown: com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity.Phonenumber.customer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.PhonenumbersApplication.main(PhonenumbersApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity.Customer.phone, referenced property unknown: com.phonenumbers.phonenumbers.entity.Phonenumber.customer
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: There is no field `customer` on entity `Phonenumber`, but this is implied by the `mapedBy = "customer"` in the `@OneToOne`-annotation. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one over at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one).

Comment: so even if it's a unidirectional join ?

Comment: If it is unidirectional, then the side having the `@OneToOne` annotation must be the owning side. This is not the case since no `@JoinColumn` is defined and the `mappedBy`-attribute is set. Please read the tutorial I linked in my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043778/inserting-data-to-2-joined-tables-using-jpa#comment122025038_69043778).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "c_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "c_address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
    private Phonenumber phone;
}
```